# ¿Como asignar un valor a un string de una struct?

Tags: c, string, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy haciendo este sencillo programa para ver como funcionan los structs en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Libro{
    int paginas;
    char autor[15];
};


int main(){
    struct Libro libro;
    libro.paginas = 8;
    libro.autor = "Manuel";

    printf("paginas: %d\n", libro.paginas);
    printf("autor: %s\n", libro.autor);

    return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo, me da problemas al imprimir el nombre del autor:

> error: assignment to expression with array type
> 12 | libro.autor = "Manuel";
> | ^

No entiendo donde está el fallo yo que he seguido el mismo procedimiento que para imprimir el número de páginas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > error: assignment to expression with array type
> > 12 | libro.autor = "Manuel";
> > | ^

Debes tener en cuenta que el identificador `autor` es simplemente un alias (*o referencia*) de la dirección base del *array*, por lo tanto, no ocupa memoria. Entonces, el compilador dará error de compilación porque `autor` es un alias y por ende, no le puedes asignar nada, no se lo trata como una *variable*.

En este caso, no queda de otra que usar la función [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) para poder copiar la cadena literal en el *array*.

**Solución:**

```c
#include <string.h> /* strcpy */

struct Libro
{
    int paginas;
    char autor[15];
};

int main()
{
    struct Libro libro;
    libro.paginas = 8;
    strcpy(autor, "Manuel"); //sin error :D
    printf("paginas: %d\n", libro.paginas);
    printf("autor: %s\n", libro.autor);
    return 0;
}
```

También tienes otra solución y es cambiando la declaración del miembro `autor` a:

```c
struct Libro
{
    int paginas;
    const char* autor;
};
```

En este caso, el identificador `autor` es un puntero (*y si se lo trata como una variable*) y si ocupará memoria. Por lo tanto, al hacer esta asignación será válido:

```c
libro.autor = "Manuel";
```

Y esto se debe porque `autor` es un puntero, en la cual, recibirá la dirección base de la cadena `Manuel`. También se debe tomar en cuenta que la cadena *Manuel* en realidad es un bloque de memoria donde están los caracteres.

**Solución 2:**

```c
struct Libro
{
    int paginas;
    const char* autor;
};

int main()
{
    struct Libro libro;
    libro.paginas = 8;
    libro.autor = "Manuel";
    printf("paginas: %d\n", libro.paginas);
    printf("autor: %s\n", libro.autor);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una confusión de conceptos: `char autor[15]` no es una cadena de caracteres, son quince caracteres organizados en una formación.

Lo que quieres hacer es copiar un valor dentro:

```
memcpy(libro.autor, "Manuel", 7);
```